# The relation between "love" and "sun"

Tags: etymology

As much I know there are a kind of relation between *love* and *sun* in some languages. For example, in Persian, we say exactly the same word for both of them: مهر means *sun*, *sunlight*, *love*.
In Turkish, *aşık* means *the man who loves* and *ışık* means *light* (mainly for sunlight).

I think there is the same relation between *flamo* and *amo* in Esperanto if we consider the sun as a ball of fire.

Do you agree with this idea?
Do you know the same relation in other languages?

Answer (score 3):

flamo is from Latin flamma, via or influenced by many Romance and Germanic descendents, which Wiktionary gives the etymology "From Proto-Italic *flagmā, from Proto-Indo-European *bʰl̥g- (“to shimmer, gleam, shine”)."([Wiktionary flamma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flamma#Latin))

amo is from Latin amo, which Wiktionary gives the etymology

"From Proto-Italic *amāō, of disputed etymology. Possibly from Proto-Indo-European *am-a-, *am- (“mother, aunt”), a lost nursery-word of the papa-type. Compare amita (“aunt”), Old High German amma (“nurse”).

Alternatively, Olav Hackstein and Michiel De Vaan suggest a derivation from Proto-Indo-European *h₃emh₃- (“to seize, to take hold”) via Proto-Italic *amāō (“to take hold”), applying a semantic shift “to take by the hand” > “to regard as a friend” > “to love, to be fond of”." ([Wiktionary amo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amo#Latin))

That is, there's no evidence that those two words are related.

I'd question the Turkish connection, as well. While English "love" translates into many Turkish words, including âşık([Wiktionary âşık](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A2%C5%9F%C4%B1k)), aşk([Wiktionary aşk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C5%9Fk#Turkish)) seems to be the core word. aşk is "From Ottoman Turkish عشق‎ ('aşk), from Arabic عِشْق‎ (ʿišq).", whereas ışık is "From Ottoman Turkish ایشق‎ (ışık), akin to Old Turkic [script needed] (yaşuk, “light, sun”), derived from Old Turkic [script needed] (yaşu-, “to shine”). See ışımak. Cognate with Azerbaijani işıq (“light”), Turkmen yşyk (“light”)."([Wiktionary ışık](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C4%B1%C5%9F%C4%B1k)) That is, aşk is ultimately Semitic and ışık is ultimately Turkish. It's easy to find connections if you search for words and ignore the etymology. If sun doesn't work, look for light or flame; sooner or later you'll find a connection.

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks; but in farsi and mainly mystical poems(for example, the Masnavi) there are so many hints about the relation between those words. I mean direct mention in meaning. sun(fire) to love and vice versa. so I think it was not a blind(easy) search.

Comment: @MasoudB مهر is indeed the same word for love and Sun. It would be interesting to look at other Indo-Iranian languages, though it seems to be a Persian only feature; the rest of the world doesn't have Mithra as a historical deity and doesn't have the connections caused by that. Ignoring known etymologies and looking for close enough words (sun - light - flame) until you find one is a notorious source of bad linguistics.

Comment: @PeterSmith, I think it is not only for Mithraism. as written in the bible, "God is Love" and "God is light". there is a connection between them in nature. and all languages comes from nature.

Comment: @MasoudB Who is Peter Smith?

Comment: sorry :) I think the tip box recommend your username for mentioning :)